# aws-sdk-js E2 createVPC is executed twice while waiting adding a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-sdk-js

```
    ec2
      .createVpc(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
          // an error occurred
        } else {
          logger.log.info(
            `Deployment VPC ${deployment.name} has been created.`
          );
          db.saveData(data, deployment.name);

          return data;
        }
      })
      .promise()
```

I was trying to run this code above, which is the most simplest resource in the docs. But when I added `.promise()` the create operation was triggered twice. When I remove it, it creates only one instance of VPC. But I need to access the information about the created resource in order to save it to the database.

Comment: what else do you need than data in the callback?

Comment: I need just the data. This is fine I am able to retrieve them. But I don't want to the function to create two vpc resources.

Comment: This is the result of every run. [2022-01-08T14:16:16+01:00] INFO: Deployment VPC test has been created.
[2022-01-08T14:16:16+01:00] INFO: Deployment VPC test has been created.

Comment: Either use `const rc = ec2.createVpc(params).promise();` or `ec2.createVpc(params, (err, data) => { // callback handler here });`. Do not use the promisified variant of the SDK call with a callback (it will invoke the API request twice). Not 100% sure why it does this, but it's perhaps some oddity of the AWS implementation that added the `.promise()` feature.

Comment: Ah, I see you opened an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4004) but closed it as "user error".

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this happens because you mix two ways of triggering a request - providing a callback and calling a promise. If you want to use promises, you should process the returned data in `then()` (or use `await`).

Example with `then()`:

```
ec2.createVpc(params).promise().then((data) => {
    logger.log.info(
       `Deployment VPC ${deployment.name} has been created.`
    );
    db.saveData(data, deployment.name);
    return data;
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.Based on the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html this is a recommended as well.

Comment: What exactly does not work in this case? Does it make no requests or is something else wrong?

Comment: Nono, everything works, but it get requested twice. I call the function one time and it creates two resources. When I delete `.promise`, it creates only one resources as it should be originally.

Comment: my point is i want to call return the promise without creating two resources of the same resource

Comment: If that is what you see even when you do not include a callback in the `createVpc()` you should probably file a bug report (note: I've eidted my answer as it was actually missing a `promise()` call).

Comment: I will. thank you